# Links do not get rendered in a table using GitHub Action's summary feature

Tags: javascript, github-actions, github-flavored-markdown

If I call the following code in a GitHub action:

```js
summary
  .addHeading("Links", 2)
  .addTable([
    [{ data: 'Site', header: true }, { data: 'Url', header: true }],
    ["Google", "[google.com](https://google.com)"]
  ]
).write();
```

I would expect it to make a table like:

### Links

| Site | Url |
| --- | --- |
| Google | [google.com](https://google.com) |

Instead, the url field does not get rendered as a link, and, instead of being [google.com](https://google.com), it is `[google.com](https://google.com)`.

It ends up looking something like this:

### Links

| Site | Url |
| --- | --- |
| Google | `[google.com](https://google.com)` |

Is there a way to render the links inside the table?

Comment: Did you try [`addLink`](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/packages/core/README.md)?

Comment: It's not treated as Markdown, it directly builds an HTML table. So provide an _HTML_ link, not a Markdown one.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the comment by @jonrsharpe.

> It's not treated as Markdown, it directly builds an HTML table. So provide an HTML link, not a Markdown one.

By converting my code into an html `a` tag, it renders properly:

```js
summary
  .addHeading("Links", 2)
  .addTable([
    [{ data: 'Site', header: true }, { data: 'Url', header: true }],
    ["Google", '<a href="https://google.com">google.com</a>']
  ]
).write();
```